# Is there any way to get last N changes for a user using drive.changes.list in one API call?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are trying to get the last N changes for a user, and currently do so by getting the largestChangeId, then subtracting a constant from that and getting more changes.

As an example, we typically are making API calls with the changestamp = largestChangeId - 300, with maxResults set to 300.

We've seen as few as half a dozen changes to 180 changes come back across our userbase with these parameters.

One issue that we're running into is that the number of changes that we get back are rather unpredictable, with huge jumps in change stamps for some users and so we've have to choose between two rather unpalatable scenarios to get the last N changes.

1. Request lots of changes, which can lead to slow API calls simply because there are lots of changes.
2. Requests a small set of changes, and seek back progressively in smaller batches, which is also slow as it results in multiple RPC calls, due to multiple API calls.

Our goal is to get the last ~30 or so changes for a user as fast as possible.

As a workaround, we are currently maintaining per user state in our application to tune the max number of changes we request up or down based on the results we got for a user the last time around. However, this is somewhat fragile due to how the rate of changes incrementing for users can vary over time.

So my question is as follows:

Is there a way to efficiently get the last N changes a user, specifically in one API call ?

Answer (score 1):

ID generation is very complex, it's impossible to calculate the ID of the user's nth latest change :) Changes list actually has no features that'd be appropriate for your use case. In my  own personal opinion, changes list should be in the reverse chronological order, going to discuss it with the rest of the team.

Comment: Thanks Burcu - I agree that reverse chronological order listings would address this issue directly and would be a very welcome addition.